# iOS5: UTF-8 encoding does not work at all

Tags: cocoa, encoding, utf-8

My application is able to send the input of several textfields to a PHP script on my server using the POST function which sends the message to my email. The problem is, some characters won't get 'translated'. For example: ü -> Ã¼.

I have already checked my HTTP Header but it's still UTF-8.

I also use this code to convert the characters:

```
[textFieldName.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversation:YES];
```

What am I doing wrong? Even the PHP file has this code:

```
function mail_utf8($to,$subject = '(No subject)',$message = '',$header = ''){
    $header_ = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
    if(mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $header_ . $header)) return true;
    else return false;
  }
```

EDIT:

```
NSString *post = nil;
            post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"vorname=%@&name=%@&plz=%@&ort=%@&email=%@&geburtsdatum=%@&eventdatum=%@",
                    [textFieldVorname.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                    [textFieldName.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                    [textFieldPLZ.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                    [textFieldOrt.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                    [textFieldEmail.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                    [textFieldGeburtsdatum.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                    [textFieldEventdatum.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.url.com/document-send.php"]];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue: postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];
            [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: What are you seeing get posted to the server?

Comment: Hi Jim. I can't see any post. I just see the output in my email. How can I have a look at the data posted to the server?

Comment: Have the server log it? You never specify how the server is converting the data or what input format it's expecting.

Comment: Jim you must be tolerant with me. I am not an expert :). I can see some logs, but nothing special like errors or else. Can I install something to make more data visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the error:

Like Peter Hosey said: the error was in decoding the utf-8 character set to ISO 8859-1 in php. Now this is the working code:

```
mail($email_to,$email_subject,utf8_decode($email_data),$email_header);
```

Thank you guys for helping me :)

Comment: No, that's not what `utf8_decode` does. (Like a lot of functions in PHP, it's badly named.) Read [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php): It translates text from UTF-8 *to ISO 8859-1*, which is a lossy conversion. Unless you absolutely need ISO 8859-1, which you don't when your purpose is to send mail, you should consider this data corruption.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed a similar problem POSTing JSON data by explicitly adding `charset=utf-8` to my `Content-Type` header. It may apply to your case, as well.

Try:

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: I.e., the Cocoa code is correctly generating UTF-8; the problem is that the PHP program is interpreting it as some 8-bit encoding, such as ISO 8859-1, and that's why you see “Ã¼” or whatever (the UTF-8 bytes for the correct character, interpreted in a wrong encoding). The solution, then, is to tell the PHP program that it's receiving UTF-8 so that it will decode it as such.

Comment: Thank you Rob, I tried this case but doesn't work. I think Xcode is no more the problem.. @ Peter: How would you do that?

Comment: @SaschaWieland: I think Rob's answer is on the right track, but don't know how close it is. Check on the PHP side to make sure it's getting the header and handling it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The method `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` returns a new NSString object.  You need to catch the return value and use it in place of the raw value of the field in the post data.

```
NSString *encodedText = [ textField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ] ;
NSData *postData = [ encodedText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES ] ;
```

Comment: Can you give me an example, John? Would be really appreciated :)

Comment: @sascha Edit to give an example.

Comment: Ah John. Think I am already using your code. Edited the first post to show you.